# Create a sequence with 3 cross joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

dbo.digits is a table that has 10 rows a column named n that starts from 1 to 10

• Join the dbo.digits with itself (3 times) using the aliases Hundreds, Tens and Units
• Derive a character column that supports leading zeros with the alias CharacterNumbersFromZeroTo999
• Hint: use either a union or compound predicate to create the query

The code should be something like this

```
SELECT CharacterNumbersFromZeroTo999 = 
from dbo.Digits AS Hundreds
cross join dbo.Digits AS Tens
cross join dbo.Digits AS Units
```

[image]
I first tried to use a sequence that will start with 000 and increment by 111, cast it into a char. However, how to make it fit in the hundreds, tens and units columns. At first I thought i cand mod by 10 and that would be the value for each column, but how do I keep the value for the sequence? Next challenge how to create a sequence starting at row 11. I noticed that when I run the code as SELECT* and comment out the 'characterNumbersFromZeroTo999' column. I get this output:

```
row 1  1    1   1
       1    2   1
       1    3   1
       1    4   1
       1    5   1
       1    6   1
       1    7   1
       1    8   1
       1    9   1
       1    10  1
row 11 1    1   2
       1    2   2
       1    3   2
       1    4   2
       1    5   2
       1    6   2
       1    7   2
       1    8   2
       1    9   2
       1    10  2
row 21 1    1   3
       1    2   3
       1    3   3
       1    4   3
       1    5   3
       1    6   3
       1    7   3
       1    8   3
       1    9   3
       1    10  3
row 31 1    1   4
```

I can see that for row 11 if i use those values 112 and turn it into 012 and ake a sequence that can add 111 it would work. I'm just not seeing how to do it. Any help or any link to somewhere that has a similar problem would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Is `n` a number or a character?

Answer (score 0):

*Digits* should be the numbers from 0 to 9, not numbers from 1 to 10.

You are pretty much there.  The next step is multiplication and subtract 1:

```
SELECT (hundreds.n * 100 + tens.n * 10 + units - 1) as CharacterNumbersFromZeroTo999
from dbo.Digits Hundreds cross join
     dbo.Digits Tens cross join
     dbo.Digits Units;
```

You can convert this to a string and left pad it using the conventional method:

```
SELECT right('000' + cast(hundreds.n * 100 + tens.n * 10 + units as varchar(32)), 3) as CharacterNumbersFromZeroTo999
from dbo.Digits Hundreds cross join
     dbo.Digits Tens cross join
     dbo.Digits Units;
```

Or, if you want to be clever:

```
SELECT right(cast(10000 + hundreds.n * 100 + tens.n * 10 + units as varchar(32)), 3) as CharacterNumbersFromZeroTo999
from dbo.Digits Hundreds cross join
     dbo.Digits Tens cross join
     dbo.Digits Units;
```

If the values are strings, you can just ignore them an use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT right('000' + cast(row_number() over (order by (select null)) - 1 as varchar(32)), 3) as CharacterNumbersFromZeroTo999
from dbo.Digits Hundreds cross join
     dbo.Digits Tens cross join
     dbo.Digits Units;
```

Comment: not quite what i need but I figured how o extract the ints as a character. So I ran this code  and I get the cross join as In my  post but haven't figured out how to do the sequence. Select CharacterNumbersFromZeroTo999 = 
 RIGHT(CAST(Hundreds.n AS NVARCHAR(3)) + CAST(tens.n AS NVARCHAR(3)) + CAST(Units.n AS NVARCHAR(3)), 3) 

from dbo.Digits           as Hundreds
    cross join dbo.Digits as Tens
    cross join dbo.Digits as Units

Comment: sorry don't know how to format it to come out to be read easily.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps with a minor twist with the aid of Row_Number() and Format()

```
Select Nmbrs = Format(Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) - 1,'000')
  From       Digits n1
  Cross Join Digits n2
  Cross Join Digits n3
```

Comment: I'm not sure how format works will research it and try it. I am familiar with Row_Number() Over() but why are we using (Select NULL) -1. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @XavierMaldonado format has some great features, but not known to be a perfomer.   Select null allows  a non-ordered set.